# How to Update JSON Object's state for onChange event in REACT JS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, state, onchange

I have state of **myrecords[]** which contains JSON Object in the following format:

```js
{
    "records": {
        "Master Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "43",
                "Name": "Oil and Lubricants",
                "Price": "4500",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "4500"

            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "45",
                "Name": "Lights",
                "Price": "2300",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "2300"
            }
        ],
        "Repair Solutions": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "47",
                "Name": "Steering Wheel",
                "Price": "1500",
                "VendorID": "60",
                "CompanyName": "Repair Solutions",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "1500"
            }
        ],
        
         "FiveStar Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "51",
                "Name": "Brakes",
                "Price": "234",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "234"
            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "53",
                "Name": "Clutch",
                "Price": "999",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "999"
            },
              {
                "SparePartID": "55",
                "Name": "LED",
                "Price": "288",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "288"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now Im showing this record in react js  in a way that all items are displayed in rows and grouped by their **CompanyNames** and against each Item there is an input field for Quantity. **Qty is 1 as default** for all so TotalPrice is same as UnitPrice.

Now I want that onChange of any particular input field of **Qty**, the corresponding  **TotalPrice** item in the JSON **Object** should also get updated in **myrecords[]** state. Also the **Qty** should also get updated in state of **myrecords[].**

P.S: **myrecords[]** contains JSON **object** not array.

here is my **react code for showing JSON object record**:

```js
  
  {Object.keys(this.state.myrecords).map((CompanyName, i) => (
<div key={CompanyName}>
   <h2>Supplier: {CompanyName}</h2>
   
  {this.state.myrecords[CompanyName].map((product, i) => (
  <tr>

    <td>
      <h4> {product["SparePartID"]} </h4>
    </td>

    <td>
      <h4>{product["Name"]} </h4>
    </td>

    <td>
      <h4> {product["Price"]} </h4>
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number"
      value={product["Qty"]}
      min="1"
      onChange={(e) => this.onChangeQty(product["SparePartID"], e)}/>
    </td>

    <td> $ {product["TotalPrice"]}
    </td>

  </tr>
  ))}
  
  </div>

  ))}
```

And the **onChangeQty** function is as follows**(this is where I need help)**:

```js
onChangeQty(sid,e)
{
   const items = this.state.myrecords;
  const item = items.find(item => item.SparePartID === sid);
  item.Qty = e.target.value;
  item.TotalPrice = item.Qty * item.Price;

  this.setState({
     myrecords: items
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change this

```
{this.state.myrecords[CompanyName].map((product, i) => (
```

to

```
{this.state.myrecords[CompanyName].map((product, j) => (
```

Because we already using **i** in above map also.

And then change this

```
onChange={(e) => this.onChangeQty(product["SparePartID"], e)}
```

to

```
onChange={(e) => this.onChangeQty(CompanyName, j, e)}
```

And then your onChange should be

```
onChangeQty(CompanyName,j,e)
{
   const items = {...this.state.myrecords};
  items[CompanyName][j].Qty = e.target.value;
  items[CompanyName][j].TotalPrice = e.target.value * items[CompanyName][j].Price;

  this.setState({
     myrecords: items
   });
}
```

If you don't like index based onChange you can also do like below(sid based). just pass `CompanyName,sid,e)` on this function `onChange={(e) => this.onChangeQty`:

```
onChangeQty(CompanyName,sid,e)
{
   const items = {...this.state.myrecords};
  const j = items[CompanyName].findIndex(item => item.SparePartID === sid);
  items[CompanyName][j].Qty = e.target.value;
  items[CompanyName][j].TotalPrice = e.target.value * items[CompanyName][j].Price;

  this.setState({
     myrecords: items
   });
}
```

Warning: Code not tested. Please check and let me know :)

Comment: Thanks Rahul. It solved my issue. I have one more question: if I wanna have a separate GrandTotal for each Company's items like if 3 companies items I have, I wanna save each Company's Total in 3 different states and show it separately (coz I wanna handle order of each Company separately). How to do it? Please Reply

Comment: Where you want to show `<td>Grand Total: $ {this.state.myrecords[CompanyName].reduce((oldValue, product) =>product.TotalPrice+oldValue,0)}
    </td>`. You can also write this logic in separate function also. See more about `reduce` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp). I hope you got the idea :). Please upvote if found this helpful

Comment: Thanks but this is just concatenating my all prices instead of sum. Or is there any other way to save the all Grandtotals in an array with index and fetch it index wise?

Comment: They are concatenating because they are strings. Add a plus sign `reduce((oldValue, product) =>+product.TotalPrice+oldValue,0)`

Comment: Thanks I got it fixed by **parseInt**. But How Can I store all these grandTotals in a state or array? Coz I want to use them later in order processing.  :(

Comment: you can make a function in which you can simply use reduce multiple times `Object.keys(this.state.myrecords).reduce((old, CompanyName) => +old+this.state.myrecords[CompanyName].reduce((oldValue, product) =>product.TotalPrice+oldValue,0),0)`  to get grandTotal anywhere

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find an item in `this.state.myrecord`. But you should in the specific company. Here is the [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/embed/82x6kvppw2).

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const RECORDS = {
  "Master Automotives": [
    {
      SparePartID: "43",
      Name: "Oil and Lubricants",
      Price: "4500",
      VendorID: "48",
      CompanyName: "Master Automotives",
      Qty: 1,
      TotalPrice: "4500"
    },
    {
      SparePartID: "45",
      Name: "Lights",
      Price: "2300",
      VendorID: "48",
      CompanyName: "Master Automotives",
      Qty: 1,
      TotalPrice: "2300"
    }
  ],
  "Repair Solutions": [
    {
      SparePartID: "47",
      Name: "Steering Wheel",
      Price: "1500",
      VendorID: "60",
      CompanyName: "Repair Solutions",
      Qty: 1,
      TotalPrice: "1500"
    }
  ],

  "FiveStar Automotives": [
    {
      SparePartID: "51",
      Name: "Brakes",
      Price: "234",
      VendorID: "70",
      CompanyName: "FiveStar Automotives",
      Qty: 1,
      TotalPrice: "234"
    },
    {
      SparePartID: "53",
      Name: "Clutch",
      Price: "999",
      VendorID: "70",
      CompanyName: "FiveStar Automotives",
      Qty: 1,
      TotalPrice: "999"
    },
    {
      SparePartID: "55",
      Name: "LED",
      Price: "288",
      VendorID: "70",
      CompanyName: "FiveStar Automotives",
      Qty: 1,
      TotalPrice: "288"
    }
  ]
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    records: RECORDS
  };

  onChangeQty = (companyName, sid, e) => {
    const { records } = this.state;

    const newQty = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
      records: {
        ...records,
        [companyName]: records[companyName].map(product =>
          product.SparePartID === sid
            ? {
                ...product,
                Qty: newQty,
                TotalPrice: newQty * product.Price
              }
            : product
        )
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { records } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {Object.keys(records).map((CompanyName, i) => (
          <div key={CompanyName}>
            <h2>Supplier: {CompanyName}</h2>
            {records[CompanyName].map((product, i) => (
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <h4> {product["SparePartID"]} </h4>
                </td>

                <td>
                  <h4>{product["Name"]} </h4>
                </td>

                <td>
                  <h4> {product["Price"]} </h4>
                </td>

                <td>
                  <input
                    type="number"
                    value={product["Qty"]}
                    min="1"
                    onChange={e =>
                      this.onChangeQty(CompanyName, product["SparePartID"], e)
                    }
                  />
                </td>

                <td> $ {product["TotalPrice"]}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is `this.state.myrecords` is an object, so directly we can't use `find` on that. Also you need to use [updater function (check doc for more details)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#setstate).

Solution to your problem is: Pass the companyName also in onChange function, then run the loop only of specific company details array. Passing company name will help you to update the state easily, otherwise you need to run the loop on all the arrays.

Like this:

```
onChange={(e) => this.onChangeQty(product["SparePartID"], CompanyName, e)}

onChangeQty(sid, companyName, e) {
  const value = e.target.value;
  this.setState(prevState => {

    return {
      myrecords: {
        ...prevState.myrecords,
        [companyName]: prevState.myrecords[companyName].map(el => {
          if(el.SparePartID === sid) {
            return { ...el, Qty: value, TotalPrice: (el.price * value) }
          }
          return el;
        });
      }
    }
  };
}
```